# Koala Ruby Facebook: Refresh access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using facebook koala gem in RoR. I just want to use it to search events and places. So I do not need any authentication for any user. I simply want to just use an access token to fire the search API. But the access token I'm using is from the Graph API explorer, so it expires after a certain period of time. I want to use an access token for life long and if not then wanted a way to refresh the expired access token in Koala Gem.

Comment: How to extend tokens is described in detail in the docs. // But in general, you should have a logged-in user when you are performing searches. You should not use this endpoint to built anything that just constantly “sucks” data, without an actual user requesting it. Search results are tailored to users anyway.

Comment: @CBroe so you mean we should access with a user account from the server to perform the request? I know how to log in via javascript, but how would you do that on rails?

Comment: I solved using `Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new( myAppID, mySecretToken ).get_app_access_token`